# Workflow loop from one stage to another

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I created a workflow with 3 stages and each is a department. When you submit a form it must be approved by depA, depB and depC, however if deptB or depC reject it, the user must submit again but this time the form and workflow must skip depA. What conditions and rules should I use to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would create three columns

`Dept A Approved`

`Dept B Approved`

`Dept C Approved`

Whenever each department approves, the column value changes to `Approved by <User>`. Then whenever the workflow starts again, it will know that the Dept A approved the list item.

Comment: Alright, will try that!

Comment: I didn't quite get it, I'm a bit new to complex workflows

Comment: Make a step/stage for each Approval. If Dept A does not equal Approved, send a task to Dept A.

Comment: Ok but how can the workflow tell which user got his form rejected and who is re-submitting the form?

Comment: that should be in the "Start an Approval Process" action, which will show up in the workflow status page.